# Count doubles in a zip of lists

Tags: list

I'm having a little trouble with lists.

I'm doing a random walk with self-avoing walk, i.e. you cannot walk over the same place two times.

I am recording the coodinates in two lists, x and y so I have something like this: (0,0),(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(2,0).... However this is just a normal random walk, because I can have repeated coordiates. My idea is to put a condition in the loop,  but here is where I have problems.

How can I tell my code to avoid repeated coordinates? For example, I have

```
coords=zip(x,y)
for i in coords:
   if i "is repeated":
       "dont go to this coord"
   else:
       "go there".
```

This is just an example, I have the code written for the "dont go to this coord" and "go there", I just need help to write the condition "if i is repeted".

Thanks

Comment: Store them in an array and check if `i`is in that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the concept:

```
coords=zip(x,y)
used_coords = []

for i in coords:
   if i in used_coords:
       "dont go to this coord"
   else:
       "go there".

   used_coords.append(i)
```